Enabling Null Sessions on an Active Directory Environment
I did setup an active directory environment with virtual machines and I'd like to enable null sessions on rpc and smb protocols.
the purpose is to be able to extract domain usernames with the following commands

rpcclient -U "" -N -c enumdomusers 

crackmapexec smb "" --users -u "" -p ""


I already did set the following registry keys to false and allowed anonymous logons in the gpo:

restrictanonymous in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
restrictanonymoussam in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Lsa
RestrictNullSessAccess in HKLM\System\CurrentControlSet\Services\RpcSs

I also did set up those settings on the default domain policy

Network access: Allow anonymous SID/Name translation Enabled
Network access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts Disabled
Network access: Do not allow anonymous enumeration of SAM accounts and shares Disabled
Network access: Let Everyone permissions apply to anonymous users Enabled
Network access: Named Pipes that can be accessed anonymously COMNAP, COMNODE, SQL\QUERY, LLSRPC, BROWSER, netlogon, samr
Network access: Restrict anonymous access to Named Pipes and Shares Disabled

